# how to group the records Date wise and Userwise

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a Enquiry table in below format

```
Date       | Status     | Username
01-Jan-2015| May Join   | John
01-Jan-2015| Interested | David
02-Jan-2015| Interested | John
02-Jan-2015| Interested | David
02-Jan-2015| Interested | John
```

I need to generate user base reports for the same till now i wrote a query for the same. But i need defined status break up based on the same report like this

```
Date        | Username | Interested | May Join
01-Jan-2015 | John     |     0      |   1
02-Jan-2015 | John     |     2      |   0
```

My Query now:

```
select Date = convert(date,CONVERT(nvarchar(10),Log,101)), Interested = COUNT(Status), May_Join=(Status) from tblenquiry where convert(date,CONVERT(nvarchar(10),Log,101)) between '01-Jan-15' and '02-jan-15' and User_ID='John' group by convert(date,CONVERT(nvarchar(10),Log,101))
```

Kindly Advise and help

Comment: Gazillion no. of times this question has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Username,
    Interested  = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Interested' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [May Join]  = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'May Join' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Enquiry
GROUP BY Date, Username
```